# Is there a better way to use d3 to display a dictionary of information?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dictionary of information that can change over time.
F.e.:

```
  at time t0 the dictionary is { "title":"hello world","content":"info about the world"},
  at time t1 the dictionary changed to { "title":"new world","content":"new info"}
```

How can I best use d3 to create&update dom nodes to display this info ?

Currently, I am thinking about doing something like this:

```
function createOrUpdate(dict) {
   var h1Sel = d3.select("#div").selectAll("h1").data([dict]);
   h1Sel.enter().append("h1");
   h1Sel.text(dict.title);
   var contentSel =d3.select("#div").selectAll("div").data([dict]);
   contentSel.enter().append("div");
   contentSel.text(dict.content);
}
```

now I should be able to call:

```
createOrUpdate(dict_t0); // creates dom nodes
createOrUpdate(dict_t1); // only updates them
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: It sounds like you wouldn't need to use D3 for this as you have only one object.

Comment: For starters, your example code won't actually update anything, since' you're only setting text on an `enter()` selection.  Check out the [General Update Pattern](bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218‎) tutorials to get you started.  For the more general case of how to efficiently use d3, you'll need to give us a more real-world example.  Do you really only have the one data object/dictionary, or do you have a collection of similar objects?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff it is an array with a single item, the dictionary.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Thanks! Updated the code. The example is actually very close to the real use case. The dictionary contains meta data that would come from a stream of live data and needs to be displayed along with other data.

Comment: @JE42 I think you've answered your own question with the update; that's the formal way to do it in d3 (except that you'd usually make the text a function of the bound data, but it doesn't make a difference in this case).  Of course, the power of d3 is that nearly the exact same code could be used to update an entire list of data.  For just changing one entry, the code is a little wordy -- but no more than using raw Javascript, and if you're using d3 for other things on the pad, it makes sense to use it.

Comment: @AmeliaBR thanks I was wondering exactly that. Since I am new to D3 I was wondering if I oversaw some nifty function/functionality that D3 has to offer for my use case. I guess, I will go ahead then and factor out this code into its own function to make it more reusable.